# How to design a strategy whose PnL is proportion to correlation?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, correlation

I'm reading about this correlation breakout strategy, whose pnl is proportional to

$$E[PnL] \sim (\rho_{1D} - \rho_{2D})\sigma_1 \sigma_2$$

where $\rho_{1D}$ is the correlation of daily returns, and $\rho_{2D}$ is the correlation of 2day returns.

How to actually achieve this with, if the two assets are commodity futures?

Comment: What is the source?

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for a [correlation swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_swap). There is a [PhD thesis](https://theses.hal.science/tel-03457424/) on static replication.

> Sébastien Bossu. *Static replication of European options and dynamic replication of correlation swaps*. Business administration, Université Paris-Saclay, 2021.

As you would expect, it is not a trivial task.